# Reset password HTML form - browser won't suggest password update

Tags: html, forms, forgot-password

I have a web app (angularjs 1.8) with login and reset password features. Storing passwords in browser and later autocomplete works correctly for the login form. When it comes to reset password form the browser (Edge and Firefox, not sure about others yet) doesn't trigger the "update password" popup after user submits new password. I mean this kind of popup:

[image]

Here is the reset password form:

```
<form name="resetPassword" ng-submit="...">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="new-password">New password</label>
            <input type="password" id="new-password" name="NewPassword" autocomplete="new-password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="NewPasswordVerify">Confirm password</label>
            <input type="password" id="NewPasswordVerify" name="NewPasswordVerify" autocomplete="new-password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

Password form is submitted using angularjs ng-submit and sent to server with angularjs $http service. I know that the form is missing an `<input />` with username and that the browser doesn't know which username to update the password for. Still adding such input with correct username doesn't help triggering the browser update-password popup. Is there anything specific I need to do so the browser automatically suggests to update the stored password?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.